# Adding a special image to special group prices

Tags: image, customer-group

In my store i have a group called "loyal customers" This group of customers gets a special price which i can set in the backend under product-> prices-> group prices. Is there a way of the products with these special group prices to display a lil image in the corner of the product image (like some sites do with products on sale) but the image should of display if the customer is logged in and is within the "loyal customer" group??

Thank you for your help if you can.

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$enable_upsell =  Mage::getStoreConfig('midmedssettings/labels/enable_upsell');
$replace_upsell =  Mage::getStoreConfig('midmedssettings/labels/replace_upsell');

$helper = $this->helper('midmedssettings/image');
list($defaultImgX, $defaultImgY) = $helper->getDefaultSize();
list($imgX, $imgY) = $helper->getMainSize();
if ( $imgX > 800 ) {
    $imgX = 800;
    $imgY = $helper->calculateHeight($imgX);
}

$product_img_box_width = $defaultImgX;
if ( $defaultImgX != $imgX ) {
    $product_img_box_width = $imgX;
}
//add image border
$product_img_box_width += 18;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="product-view">

<div class="rcolumn"> 

<div class="additionaldata">
   <ul>
   <li class="freedelivery"><strong>FREE!!</strong> Delivery over £75 exc VAT<br><span style="color:#666666">more information on delivery</span></li>
    <?php   
                        $_direct_delivery_product = $this->htmlEscape($_product->getdirect_delivery_product());
                        if ($_direct_delivery_product == 1){
                        ?>
                       <li class="deliverytime">Direct Delivery Item - delivery may take longer than usual</li>
                            <?php
} else {
?>                           <li class="nextday">Next Day Delivery Available<br>Standard Delivery 1 - 5 working days</li>
                          <?php
}
?>
<li class="globe">International Delivery Available</li>
<li class="pricebeat">Seen this cheaper elsewhere? Fill out our simple <strong><A HREF="javascript:popUp('http://www.midmeds.com/tinc?key=VlYdESS9&formname=pricematch')">Pricematch Form</A></strong> and we will beat the price by 3%*</li>
<li class="bulk">Buying in larger quantities?
Phone for a quote - <br> 0845 00 34 212</li>
<li class="paymentoptions"> Payment and Security </li>
<div class="credit"> 30 days credit account </div>
<div class="nhs">We accept NHS purchase orders </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="paymentoptionsdcc">Credit Cards Accepted </div> 
</ul>
    </div>
</div> 
    <div class="product-essential">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
        <div class="no-display">
            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
        </div>

        <div class="product-img-box" style="width:<?php echo $product_img_box_width; ?>px">
            <?php echo $this->helper('midmedssettings')->getLabel($_product);  ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
            <?php       
        $_isLoggedIn = $this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn();
        if($_isLoggedIn == true){
        $_myGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();          
        if($_myGroupId == 4){
        echo '<img style="float: left; margin: 2px;" src="/media/catalog/category/LMC-img.gif">';
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="product-shop"> 
            <div class="product-shop-info">

<?php
if($_product->isSaleable())
{
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId('*');
$quote->addProduct($_product);
$quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();
$rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRatesCollection();

foreach ($rates as $rate)
{
echo $rate->getPrice();
}
}
?>  
                <div class="product-name">
                    <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
                </div>
                <?php if ($this->hasOptions()):?>

                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>

                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
                <?php if(!$_product->getAWDisableOutOfStock()): ?>      
   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="aw-cat-perm-notify"><?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('catalogpermissions/general/product_notice'); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

                <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>
         <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>

                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                <!-- RELATED -->
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content_related2') ?>
        <!-- RELATED -->
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
         <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
                <?php endif;?>
 <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
        <?php endif;?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
        <div class="clearer"></div></div>

    </form>
```

Comment: Did you get a chance try out the code I provided?

Comment: just about to, will let you know how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement this code on the product view and adjust as needed. Change the value #4 to the Group ID of your "loyal customers".

```
<?php       
        $_isLoggedIn = $this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn();
        if($_isLoggedIn == true){
        $_myGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();          
        if($_myGroupId == 4){
        echo '<img style="float: left; margin: 2px;" src="/path-to-image/loyal.jpg' alt="'loay customner'">';

                }
            }
            ?>
```

I use this code to show me cost pricing of my products  on the fly when browsing to do some spot checking.

Comment: no its not working... i think it is because of where i am adding the code. im adding it to where my image is created on my product page (media.phtml) is that wrong? and if it is could u give me a better idea of where to put it, cos in my "view.phtml" there is no image being created?? im rather new at this so sorry for the questions lol

Comment: @Adam Allen - start simple. Get the code working on the product view first. Then get fancy and implement it with the media.phtml file. :) I'd have to see your view.phtml file to give you a better idea of where to put it but it should be appearing pretty much anywhere you place it.

Comment: ok dokie, i will keep messing around with ti and if i am still having trouble tomoz i will show you my view.phtml. Thank  you

Comment: What are you using for the path to your image? Make sure you can display the image correctly outside of the code I provided and then bring it in. Also be sure that you have the correct ID for your loyal customer group. Let me know. SR

Comment: im getting this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/senorehe/public_html/app/design/frontend/midmeds/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml on line 125

The line is  echo '<img style="float: left; margin: 2px;" src="/path-to-image/loyal.jpg" alt="'loay customner'">';

obviously i did change the img src but just copy and pasted yours to make it easier lol

Comment: ok i got rid of the error by getting rid of the ALT so my product is displaying again but no image (new image, still has product image)

do you have somewhere i can send my View.phtml to see if i have put it in the correct place or shall i just post on my Question?

Comment: Post it in your question, I'll see whats going on. SR